# How can i create button above inAppWebView?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, webview

**this is my code**

```
  Future<void> _launchInWebViewOrVC(Uri url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      webViewConfiguration: const WebViewConfiguration(
          enableJavaScript: false,
          headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'}),
    )) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

i hope to create close button when user click url and state is inappWebviewing

I want to make an `close button` on the cell phone screen, not the back button of the cell phone or the gesture of the iPhone, so that it can be terminated when pressed.

please help me thanks you

Answer (score 1):

you can use Stack widget in inAppWebView and after use position widget to adjust in full screen alignment.